# Why my byte[] gets UTF-8 encoded by HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, encoding, jasper-reports

I have a very strange problem while downloading a file from my Spring Controller, first of all here's the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/id/{fileId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(@PathVariable("fileId") String fileId, HttpServletResponse response) {

    // check if file exists
    if (files.containsKey(fileId)) {
        response.reset();

        // StoredFile contains name, extension and content (byte[]) of the file
        StoredFile file = files.remove(fileId);
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getFullName());

        byte[] payload = file.getContent();         
        response.setContentLength(payload.length);

        // writing file on disk
        File f = new File("/" + fileId + ".pdf");
        try {
            FileCopyUtils.copy(payload, f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // send the same payload to the client for download
        try {
            response.getOutputStream().write(payload);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
        }
    }
}
```

So, I retrieve a previously stored file, then I save its content on disk and send the same content to a client for download, but here's the strange thing: the two files are different!

The saved file is ok (it's a jasper report pdf).

The downloaded file displays nothing, and looking inside it with a binary editor I found the "EF BF BD" byte sequence that displays an UTF-8 unrecognised character.

I don't understand when the content of my byte[] is interpreted as UTF-8 and why the byte sequence is inserted; should I set the encoding somewhere even if I'm writing raw bytes inside the output stream?

I tried to set the response charactr encoding to different encoding with no change in the result, but I hadn't expected any since I'm not transferring text...

Any idea?

Comment: I also tried to return a ResponseEntity<byte[]> but the same encoding occurs in the final downloaded file. Can anybody give me a suggestion for where should I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works! 
A colleague downloaded my branch and run the application... The downloaded file was ok. So I tried to pass the code to another colleague and then to deploy it on the test server, always getting positive results. 
The issue must be in some workspace or machine setting, but for sure not in the code.